# correct PATH for zshrc in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, zshrc

I'm on Windows 10, installed WSL2 with Ubuntu v20 and then I installed Oh My Zsh. I thought I had everything working but when I went to type `code .`, in my Ubuntu terminal I got the error `zsh: command not found: code`.

When I do `echo $PATH` I get:
`/home/robbie/.nvm/versions/node/v18.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/robbie/.yarn/bin`

My `.zshrc` file looks like (I removed a bunch of the comments for this snippet):

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
plugins=(git node npm nvm z yarn)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

source /home/robbie/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

On VSCode I have the Remote WSL extension installed and set default/enabled on Ubuntu under Remote Explore.

In Windows 10 under Environment Variables, under `Path` I have a variable `C:\Users\RobbieC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

I have tried uncommenting `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` - shutting down WSL, rebooting, no luck. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Remote WSL extension, rebooting computer, etc. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

Open your regular Debian terminal App(Ensure you are in the debian home directory). Type `ls -la` there you will find the .zshrc file. Then remove the VScode Path you added.